# RxJava 2.0 conversion to generic loses all types

Tags: android, generics, rx-java2, rx-android

I've inherited some code I need to generalize, which uses RxJava 2.0 for some stuff - namely requesting the data from a REST service (using Retrofit) and then parsing that using our own custom parser.

We have two slightly different implementations of the same flow, and I've been trying to unify them, without much luck - as soon as I start using the generic parent types, `subscribe()` loses every type and returns Objects instead.

The code is the following (simplified a bit to match NDA):

```
// MyStuff is a base class, which has two child classes inheriting
// Base processing is done in the abstract class, while type-specific
// processing is done in ParserOne and ParserTwo
public abstract class ParserBase<T extends MyStuff> {
    // This call will be specific to the actual MyStuffOne or MyStuffTwo objects, hence abstract
    public abstract Flowable<TargetModel> parse(Flowable<T> parsestuff);
    // These two calls are applied to the generic MyStuff class
    // and are shared between MyStuffOne and MyStuffTwo 
    public Flowable<Map<long,MyModel>> parseOneImpl(Flowable<T> parsestuff) { /* impl here */ }
    public Single<Map<long,MyModel>> parseTwoImpl(Flowable<T> parsestuff) { /* impl here */ }
}

public class MyStuff {
    // Some common fields here
}

public class MyStuffOne extends MyStuff {
    // Some MyStuffOne specific fields here
}

public class MyStuffTwo extends MyStuff {
    // Some MyStuffTwo specific fields here
}

public class ParserOne extends ParserBase<MyStuffOne> {
    @Override 
    public Flowable<TargetModel> parse(Flowable<MyStuffOne> parsestuff) { /* impl 1 here */ }
}

public class ParserTwo extends ParserBase<MyStuffTwo> {
    @Override 
    public Flowable<TargetModel> parse(Flowable<MyStuffTwo> parsestuff) { /* impl 2 here */ }
}

public class MyClassOne {

    protected void call() {
        ParserOne parser = new ParserOne();
        callGeneric(parser);
    }

    protected void callGeneric(ParserBase<?> parser) {
        // Common implementation here
        parser.parseOneImpl(whatever).subscribe(
            result -> { /* result ends up being Object instead of Map<Long,MyModel> */ }, 
            throwable -> { /* throwable also ends up being Object */ });
    }
}

public class MyClassTwo extends MyClassOne {
    @Override
    protected void call() {
        ParserTwo parser = new ParserTwo();
        callGeneric(parser);
    }
}
```

So while the `parseOneImpl()` call has a generic parameter, it has a fixed return type - but for some reason, `subscribe()` does not see this and instead returns generic Objects. I could work around this by casting the result (which works fine, since the actual runtime object matches the return type of `parseOneImpl()`), but I'd like to avoid that.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you extend `ParserBase`, you didn't specify a generic argument to it so everything after that becomes the raw type.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part in the generification of the code - ParserOne and ParserTwo are actually extending `ParserBase<MyStuffOne>` and `ParserBase<MyStuffTwo>` respectively. Fixed it in the question.

Comment: One of the problem is `ParserBase<?>`, the other one is `T extends MyStuff`. I'm not an expert on Java generics but thinking covariantly doesn't work in Java. You should rethink your type arguments.

Comment: T extends MyStuff is needed, since the ParserBase contains some functions (namely `parseOneImpl` and `parseTwoImpl` in the example) that are shared by all parser implementations and all work on the shared MyStuff class (here MyStuff is a common response base from our API, and MyStuffOne, MyStuffTwo are specific responses that extend this base response).

For `ParserBase<?>` I could specify that `? extends MyStuff`, but I've already tried that and the issue persists. What I don't understand is why the statically typed `parseXImpl` returns an Object in Rx.

Comment: What is `TargetModel`? Is it an actual object? Also what is `MyModel`?

Comment: `TargetModel` and `MyModel` are two completely separate, open classes without any specific requirements. They are the target of these conversions.